# Vectorization of Custom Function Not Applying Function to Each Row of Series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vectorization

I have a function that returns several values when applied to a text string.

I want to apply the the function to a Pandas Series using Vectorization as outlined below (I have used vectorization in the past with single output without issues).

Example:

```
df['Column1'], df['Column2'], df['Column3'] = FUNCTION(Pandas.Series)
```

However, the vectorization seems to be passing the full Series to the function rather than applying to each element in the series as expected.

Using np.vectorize(FUNCTION)(Pandas.Series) and zip(*Pandas.Series.map(FUNCTION)  both work but speed is key here and I know that using the function directly could reduce the time significantly.

I have also converted the Series to an array with .values but I still have the same issue in that it is passing the full Series rather than applying the function to each element.

Thanks for your help,

RKB

Comment: If your `FUNCTION` only works with one element at a time, you'll have to use a map or `vectorize`.  If you want speed, then you have to rewrite the function so it works with the Series or a whole numpy array.

Comment: Thanks for your comment hpaulj.   I was under the impression that I could a function that only worked on one element with a series input from the article below.  Otherwise I would just be putting a for loop inside the function. 
 https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6

Comment: The `haversine` function in that link works with scalars and with arrays.  The first 3 approaches call that function once for each row.  They just differ in the iteration details.  The two fast ones pass whole Series or 1d arrays to that function, thus calling it only once.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj,  I missed the fact that the haversine function accepted scalars and arrays.  I think I'm stuck with using map because I need to apply the function to each element as I'm performing texts manipulation and not numerical manipulation which can be broadcast.